# Libgdx arcball camera with billboarding

Tags: android, libgdx

When I rotate my camera with rotateAround 0, 0 ,0 and then x and y then gimbal probleme will be present.

How can I implement an arcball camera right in libgdx?

Here is what I want

https://youtu.be/YxNjjyv8W0I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two rotation matrix and a camfocusvector as an arcball